# Как удалить блоки html?

Tags: google-apps-script

Мне нужно удалить блок blockquote. Как я могу это сделать?

```
<blockquote class="gmail_quote" style="margin:0px 0px 0px .8ex;border-left:1px solid rgb(204,204,204);padding-left:1ex;"><div style="line-height:18px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:rgb(0,0,0);">
....
....

</blockquote>
```

Я попробовал этот способ, но он мне не помог.

```
l_oResponse[key].message['content_html'] // Просто Html страничка

String(message_key).replace(/<blockquote[^>]*>.*<\/blockquote>/, "");
```

Comment: `// Просто Html страничка` - это не тот комментарий, который может быть полезен

Comment: У меня там просто находится html с типом str. как мне будет правильно написать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть в файле index.html будет разметка

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <blockquote cite="https://www.huxley.net/bnw/four.html">
    <p>Words can be like X-rays, if you use them properly—they’ll go through anything. You read and you’re pierced.</p>
    <footer>—Aldous Huxley, <cite>Brave New World</cite></footer>
  </blockquote>
  <p><a href="https://www.huxley.net/bnw/four.html">Huxley's Quote</a></p>
  <blockquote cite="https://www.huxley.net/bnw/four.html">
    <p>Words can be like X-rays, if you use them properly—they’ll go through anything. You read and you’re pierced.</p>
    <footer>—Aldous Huxley, <cite>Brave New World</cite></footer>
  </blockquote>
</body>

</html>
```

Тогда замена может быть такой

```js
function myFunction() {
  const content = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').getContent();
  const text = content.replace(/<blockquote[\s\S]+?\/blockquote>/gm, '');
  console.log(text);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Все хорошо работает